# Is there any advantage to asking a question here than on a dedicated forum for a specific game?

Tags: discussion

Is there really any advantage to asking a question here on Arqade Stack Exchange than on the dedicated forum for a specific game or game company?

Examples:

- Arqade.SE versus http://www.minecraftforum.net for MineCraft
- Arqade.SE versus http://forum.supercell.net for Clash Royale
- Arqade.SE versus https://support.rockstargames.com for Grand Theft Auto V

Comment: To add to the other answers, forums are usually where the devs are. If you ask for dev support on Arqade it will be off topic .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ...Arqade Stack Exchange ***instead*** of the dedicated forum...

I think you are looking at it all wrong.  Why not both?  You will get:

- Your question exposed to a greater pool of people
- Your question exposed to different groups of people (people good at answering questions, people knowledgeable in the game etc)
- A greater opportunity in finding answers (including alternative answers to the same question)
- The opportunity to share knowledge from other sites

If you only choose 1 source over the other, you may see the following problems:

---

*Arqade Problems*

- May lack experts in the game (i.e. experts may reside in the dedicated forum)
- The question may be closed as off-topic because Arqade has a narrower scope for acceptable questions (whereas a game forum will not have such restrictions)
- Arqade format doesn't allow for discussions in the question (although you can divert off into chat)

---

*Forum Problems*

- Rarely see appropriate feedback on good/bad/incorrect answers
- Can be opinionated rather than factual
- Can easily divert off-topic (depends on the moderation, but regardless forums are generally more relaxed than Arqade)
- Answers to your question are rarely maintained over time (for example, broken links, patch changes etc)

Answer (score 11):

The Arqade, like the rest of the stack exchange websites, is all about getting quality answers to questions about all games. We strive for detailed answers that will help you and others to come who might have the same problem. While you may be able to get similar information on sites dedicated to that company or game, I don't think you will find that many other sites are as dedicated to quality as us. We are community moderated, and the community is very active in making sure that we remain a quality site. A lot of our members are also experts in game knowledge in the games they play and are willing to do in depth experiments or comprehensive data collection on games to discover how mechanics work, what the recommended strategies are, secret routes and achievements, and many other aspects of games that you may have trouble with. To sum it up, we are generally more dedicated to quality answers than most other sites are.

Here are just a few examples of the types of answers I am talking about.

[Is Angry Birds deterministic?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44600/127901)
[What is the terminal velocity of a sheep?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178730/127901)
[What's the difference between life, health, armour and shield?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/266840/127901)

Answer (score 4):

## Not every game has a dedicated forum

Some games, particularly older ones, don't have a dedicated online community. For instance, we have questions on [captain-tsubasa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-tsubasa), [segasonic-the-hedgehog](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/segasonic-the-hedgehog), and the first [heroes-of-might-and-magic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-might-and-magic). A community of people who answer questions for all games is an important to getting help for games like those.